# Best practice on instantiating different types of the same es6 class

Tags: html5-canvas, es6-class

I am building an HTML5 Canvas 2d game and i have some es6 classes on my project. One of them is Obstacles. What i want to do is having the ability to create a different instance of this class depending on a given type (eg. small, thick, tall etc).

What is the best way to do this?

1. Just add another parameter to the constructor of the class and name it type?
2. Or just create subclasses of the main class Obstacle by extending it (eg. SmallObstacle, TallObstacle) given a random type value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is based around how you want to build and implement your data structures. Neither option is *necessarily* better than the other 100% of the time. I'll explain the pro's and con's of each below along with my personal solution. You can decide which one is more feasible for you to implement.

**Option 1:**

Pros:

- Easy to insert into the class and deal with later in your code
- Leaves your class neat and slimmer

Cons:

- You have to deal with it later in your code. When initializing (maybe even when updating/rendering) your code needs to interpret what the types are and build each obstacle based on that.

**Option 2:**

Pros:

- Makes an organized class
- Not much work later in your code since you're just pulling preset specifications rather than interpreting them

Cons:

- The class is much larger
- You are likely to be repeating some code (although if you do it well, you won't)

**My Opinion:**
Personally I would skip specifying "large," "medium," "tall," "wide." Instead, I would use some logic when implementing the class and make the height and width whatever I want. You could take advantage of how one can easily specify a value while also providing a default with a function constructor.

Here is a snippet example:

```js
class obstacle {
  constructor(x, y, w=150, h=150) {
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
        this.width = w; //default is 150
 this.height = h; //so it's medium or something
    this.sprite = ...; //etc.
  }
}

// Initialize 100 obstacles :P
for (let i=0; i<100; i++) {
  let x = Math.random() * scene.width;
  let y = Math.random() * scene.height;
  let foo = new obstacle(x, y);
  /* When you want different width and height instead
     of the default, construct like this:
     let bar = new obstacle(x, y, width, height);
  */
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! If it ends up working for you, I'd appreciate it if you would accept my answer :)